# Hide window scrollbar with Overflow-y set to scroll

Tags: javascript, css, touch, overflow

I came across this site Teehan and Lax (http://www.teehanlax.com/) and saw that when you click on the top menu, a set of links dropsdown. The containing div is set to

```
#main-nav-drop{
    position:fixed;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

However, when scrolling, the actual window scrollbar is hidden, both on desktop and mobile. How is this being done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On that site it is done by adding padding-right: 100px; to nav element.

Comment: Interesting solution. Are there any other ways to do this? I'm working on an off-canvas slideout responsive menu and need the menu to be scrollable. I'm looking into Overflow.js, but would like to remove the scrollbar that appears so it seems more native-like.

Comment: You can set overflow:hidden, track mousewheel event, and change scrollTop property by scroll delta. https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel might be helpful. Which solution is more likely i'm not sure.